# Embedded SQL editor for web pages

Tags: sql, editor

We are developing a web application in Java/Java EE where users should be able to type in the SQL queries, and should be able to see syntax coloring, table view, content help etc.

Please suggest any third party tools which can be embedded into webpages which does this.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can find is this http://archive.eso.org/wdb/html/wdb.html.  I have never used it and it may require an interface implentation for the specific DB you use (see the dev section http://archive.eso.org/wdb/html/doc/WDB/node1.html).

I think the problem is most web front ends specialise in one particular DBMS instead of being agnostic and most are not written in a way that enables components to be dropped into other applications.

The WDB code may give you a starting point on coding this yourself though.

Is there are particulare DBMS that you need to support?

You might have more joy looking into available third party SQL parsers and hooking them up in a web page with AJAX.  I would expect any third party library worth it's salt to already try and detect SQL injection but it would be wise to verify that's the case.